# Where would に be in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

In the sentence "Mr. Yamada goes to work at eight thirty." where would the に be placed? Would it be

> a) やまださんははちじはんしごと**に**いきます。
>   b) やまださんははちじはん**に**しごといきます。

Why?

Comment: Presumably you mean はちじ**ごろ** not はちじ**ごと**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you need to use に　after both the time phrase (where it indicates "at") and after "job" (where it indicates "to"). So the correct sentence would be:

やまださんははちじはんにしごとにいきます。

While particles are often omitted in casual speech, omitting them in written Japanese would be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: So... if this were said in a verbal conversation... you wouldn't use に at all??